# How to forecast Value-at-Risk in R with different assumptions?

Tags: value-at-risk

I'm calculating 1-day parametric VaR estimates under the assumption that the returns are distributed as a generalized error distribution.

I have the historical observations of the returns, obtained as log-difference prices.

How do I estimate in R the shape parameter of the GED to use to find the quantile?

Comment: If this is R-specific, then it is off topic. If you're looking for an answer in the form of a formula, then it's fine, but your question would benefit a lot from including links to information on the distribution and embedding in its body the formula of the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (from [this](https://www.rmetrics.org/sites/default/files/ebooks-basicr-ged.pdf) source):

```
dged <- function(x, mean = 0, sd = 1, nu = 2) {
  z = (x - mean)/sd
  lambda = sqrt(2^(-2/nu) * gamma(1/nu)/gamma(3/nu))
  g = nu/(lambda * (2^(1 + 1/nu)) * gamma(1/nu))
  density = g * exp(-0.5 * (abs(z/lambda))^nu)/sd
  density
}


gedFit <- function(x, ...) {
  start = c(mean = mean(x), sd = sqrt(var(x)), nu = 2)
  loglik = function(x, y = x) {
    f = -sum(log(dged(y, x[1], x[2], x[3])))
    f
  }
  fit = nlminb(start = start, objective = loglik, lower = c(-Inf,
                                                            0, 0), upper = c(Inf, Inf, Inf), y = x, ...)
  names(fit$par) = c("mean", "sd", "nu")
  fit
}
```

Here you can change `data` to your calculated observations:

```
set.seed(2356)
data = rnorm(1000, 0, 0.09)
fitted = gedFit(data)
parameters = fitted$par
parameters
```

Your parameters, including `nu`:

```
       mean          sd          nu 
0.003114645 0.088738398 2.409166210
```